# Присваивание высоты

Tags: jquery

Хочу сделать следующее:

1. Узнать ширину #sidebar и .main-content
2. Если ширина #sidebar меньше ширины .main-content , присвоить ширину от.main-content к нему
3. А если ширина #sidebar больше ширины .main-content то для .main-content задать ширину от #sidebar.

Я в jQuery пару дней,извините за глупый вопрос и код.

```
function Equal() {
       var mainHeight = $(".main-content").height();
       var sideHeight = $("#sidebar").height();
         if (var sideHeight > var mainHeight) {
            $(".main-content").css("height", sideHeight);
         };

         if (var sideHeight < var mainHeight) {
            $("#sidebar").css("height", mainHeight);
         };

       });
     }
```

Comment: 3 часа назад что-то похожее уже было [тут][1]

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/320301/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-javascript

Comment: if (var sideHeight > var mainHeight) {
Пишется без var.
if (sideHeight > mainHeight) {

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, вы пишите, что вы хотите проверить и изменить ширину (**width**), а по факту пытаетесь проверить и изменить высоту (**height**).
Во-вторых, вам необходимо выучить синтаксис **javascript**, прежде, чем браться за **jQuery**. Даже в таком маленьком примере вы наделали кучу ошибок.
В-третьих, в данном случае, лучше сохраняйте в переменную сам элемент, а не его высоту.

```
var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
var content = $('.main-content');

if (sidebar.width() > content.width()) {
    content.width(sidebar.width());
    console.log('--extending content');
} else {
    sidebar.width(content.width());
    console.log('--extending sidebar');
}
```

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/jn2j3/)**

Comment: Большое спасибо,я думал про высоту но написал про ширину :D